# How to figure out what is going on with this nice CSS horizontal menu?

Tags: css

[edit] initially I thought he did it with javascript, as it actually turns out, he chose a CSS only approach.

So I stumbled over this blog:
[david walsh's blog about jquery css etc](http://davidwalsh.name/)
I really like the horizontal menu. I want to build something similar. I would have loved to look at how he did it.

What is a good way to find out what is going on there?

Comment: You should add the css tag to this...

Comment: this question should be fine now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be all CSS. In chrome, if you inspect element on one of the menu items, you'll see the basic structure as:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class=>
            <a>Link</a><!-- this is the main menu item -->
            <div>  <!-- this is the submenu -->
                <ul>
                    <li></li> <!-- submenu item -->
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Now, knowing all of this, you can click the button to activate hover on various elements, so you know which is getting the new styles.

When I activate hover on the nav > ul > li the submenu becomes visible.

```
nav>ul>li:hover .dropdown {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

When activating hover on the nav>ul>li>a, the little image pops up.

```
nav>ul>li.connect>a:hover,
nav>ul>li.connect>a:active,
nav>ul>li.connect>a:focus {
    background-position: -324px 46px;
}
```

Comment: +1, nice work... and here I thought he actually wanted to "debug/halt javascript"

Answer (score 0):

That header looks like pure CSS to me, but in general, if you're using Firebug, I'm pretty sure you can stick a breakpoint on an event by looking through the /events/seq/1 section of the script panel.

Comment: I don't understand what you recommended, i cannot find anything like that in the script panel.
I found this though: https://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html
you can add a break on attribute change by right clicking an html element